# PDOStatement in foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach, pdo

There is a following code:

```
<?php 

    include 'connection.php'; //$db is declared here. It's a PDO object.

    foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM names") as $row) {
        echo $row['firstname'] . $row['lastname'] . $row['postcode'] . '<br>';
    }

?>
```

The code works as expected, but I don't understand the logic behind it.

I've read on php.net that `PDO::query()` returns a `PDOStatement` object as a result set. 
So teoretically, this part: `$db->query("SELECT * FROM names")` is a `PDOStatement` object.

How does `foreach` loop through an `PDOStatement` object? Does it convert the `PDOStatement` object to an associative array? Why isn't this part: `$db->query("SELECT * FROM names") as $row` giving errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) implements [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface, which means it can be used inside a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now. But how is the result set stored inside `PDOStatement` object? In php.net description of [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) I didn't see any properties which would hold the result set value. @Yuri Fedorov

Comment: I guess that the result set is encapsulated and hidden from us, but you can try to find it in the source code: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c